# TLSv1.0, вычисление 'HMAC'

Tags: c#, ssl, tls

Здравствуйте. Прошу мне помочь, как сгенерировать HMAC от сообщения? HEX:

```
1400000cb0b513341258473a9f7f216d5545df094b1bedc5cc6b46ea891bcb6081b1266e0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b
```

Сообщение смог создать: `b0b513341258473a9f7f216d`

К сожалению не могу понять, как вычислить HMAC: `5545df094b1bedc5cc6b46ea891bcb6081b1266e`

Я использую CipherSuite: `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)` и версию TLS: `1.0`

Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#section-6.2.3.1

```
The MAC is generated as:

HMAC_hash(MAC_write_secret, seq_num + TLSCompressed.type +
          TLSCompressed.version + TLSCompressed.length +
          TLSCompressed.fragment));
```

Здесь:

```
seq_num - 64-битное число, счетчик, для Finished всегда 0, так как оно первое сообщение которое зашифровано
TLSCompressed.type - 1 байт, тип сообщения, для Finished - это handshake
TLSCompressed.version - 2 байта, версия SSL
TLSCompressed.length - 2 байта, длина сообщения
TLSCompressed.fragment - само сообщение
```

HMAC вычисляется так:

```
byte[] key = ...; // один из ключей, вычисленный на этапе key expansion
var hmacsha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(key);
byte[] data = ...; // seq_num + type + version + length + fragment, с примера выше
byte[] hmac = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(data);
```

Comment: Хотел спросить, в качестве сообщения, нужно отправить handshake_messages?  Или FinishHash (после PRF) ?

`byte[] FinishHash = TlsUtilities.PRF_legacy(master_secret,"client finished",ByteArray.Concat(md5.ComputeHash(Tools.HexToBytes(Hash)), sha.ComputeHash(Tools.HexToBytes(Hash))),12);`

Comment: Там всего 12 байт, как в них поместятся все сообщения? Конечно нужно отправлять 12 байт после PRF функции от сообщений.

Comment: Хорошо. У меня должен получится HMAC как у клиента? Если использовать клиенские данные ?

Comment: Да, в этом и суть MAC, проверить, никто ли не подменил данные. Все должно совпасть.

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрите пожалуйста, правильно ли я составил? `0000000000000000160301000C65529e39847f5f7328d62c4a`

Hash: `65529e39847f5f7328d62c4a` 

`string b = 0.ToString("X16") + "160301" + FinishHash.Length.ToString("X4") + Bit(FinishHash);`

Comment: Похоже что правильно

Comment: К сожалению, HMAC не совпадает =(. А сообщение да. Подскажите пожалуйста, по каким причинам это могло произойти?


Посмотрите пожалуйста отрывок моего кода: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/raw/5qj7WwVd)

Comment: Я не знаю, может у вас неправильно ключ сгенерирован? Длина MAC ключа может неправильная? Что бы знать наверняка, нужно брать другую имплементацию TLS и смотреть в дебаге, что на другой стороне получается.

Comment: Хорошо. [Посмотрите пожалуйста этап генерации ключей](https://pastebin.com/5Nd3v65V):

Comment: Что скажете? Код правильно написан?

Comment: Я не умею запускать и проверять код в голове :) Это не делается так. Когда я писал свой TLS сервер, код постоянно казался правильным, хотя что-то все время вычислялось неправильно. Только благодаря библиотеке BouncyCastle в режиме отладки я смог обнаружить ошибки в своем коде.

Comment: Если у вас сообщение корректно расшифровалось, значит скорее всего ключи правильные. Возможно данные над которыми считается HMAC неправильные.

Comment: Вы есть в социальных сетях? Вк, скайп?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72221/discussion-between-zergatul-and--).